# Disable Pentaho Info Logs

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

When I kick off Pentaho to run the logs start off like this...

```
NFO: Lock acquired. Setting startlevel to 100
Jan 20, 2024 7:06:24 PM org.apache.karaf.main.Main$KarafLockCallback lockAcquired
INFO: Lock acquired. Setting startlevel to 100
Jan 20, 2024 7:06:29 PM org.apache.aries.spifly.BaseActivator log
INFO: Registered provider org.eclipse.jetty.http.Http1FieldPreEncoder of service org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpFieldPreEncoder in bundle org.eclipse.jetty.http
Jan 20, 2024 7:06:29 PM org.apache.aries.spifly.BaseActivator log
INFO: Registered provider org.eclipse.jetty.security.jaspi.JaspiAuthenticatorFactory of service org.eclipse.jetty.security.Authenticator$Factory in bundle org.eclipse.jetty.security.jaspi
Jan 20, 2024 7:06:29 PM org.apache.aries.spifly.BaseActivator log
INFO: Registered provider org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.extensions.identity.IdentityExtension of service org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.extensions.Extension in bundle org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common
Jan 20, 2024 7:06:29 PM org.apache.aries.spifly.BaseActivator log
```

How can I disable all of these info logs? If there is an error message, I would love to see that, but I don't care about the rest of the logs.

Answer (score -1):

Pentaho provides multiple log levels. For viewing only the errors, i would suggest setting the log level to: **ERROR**. A screenshot is provided below for reference.

[image]